# Stuck at certain command when using macos-latest on github actions

Tags: android, macos, shell, github-actions, android-sdk-manager

Stuck at certain command when using macos-latest
I’m unable to proceed with my workflow since I stuck at a certain command as shown below

```
  - name: Install SDK manager dependencies 
      run: |
          yes | sudo sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --licenses
          yes | sudo sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --verbose --no_https ${{env.ANDROID_SDK_PACKAGES}}
```

seems that the command is accepting the license but the terminal is not terminated in order to execute the following command
note that the same command is working fine when I use it locally on my mac

screenshot
[image: output screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of yes, use `echo y`

Example:

```
echo y | sudo sdk manager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --licenses
```